# OneNote 2013 -- change the author

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

Apologies if this is the wrong forum.

My co-worker and I are sharing a OneNote 2013 notebook, and we will sometimes make updates on the same page.

We have encountered some kind of bug where, if I make changes to a page, and then he later makes changes to the same page, all of my changes are marked as having been written by him.  This makes it difficult to go back later and remember who did which tasks.

I can't give you a screenshot at this time for security reasons, but all of the text that I wrote, and also all of the text that he wrote, is marked in green (to alert me that somebody else made a change) and has a pink line down the right-hand side with his initials.

Is there an easy way to select a batch of text and change the author from him to me?

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste the text to another textbox. The username is assigned to each texbox, so you mah need to click on a blank area and paste text there. This is annoying since the text may not line up nicely.

Comment: It is indeed annoying for a few reasons.  Text boxes don't realign themselves when other text boxes change their size.  But if that's the only option -- one author per text box -- then we'll have to figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

I find there can be multiple users in a single text box that still show separately authored changes, but it seems that if the material is somehow moved in the process, that movement is, for some undiscovered reason, treated as authored by the person moving it (not just when it is cut and pasted).  The author then loses that historical credit for the work.  This appears to be a flaw in the program.

In a healthy collaborative atmosphere, I think this is fine, since teamwork is not about getting personal credit - it is about building interpersonal trust and recognition instead.  We use this as our tool a lot and it helps teach my staff to get over the need to control and stop personalizing every word.  My team now works much like a single person, supporting instead of competing, and I find my staff are learning to live a freer happier work style in the process of letting go.

However, if you really need to separate your work out, I suggest you agree to a team method and set boundaries - either working in separate text boxes, as suggested, or different pages, merging material later.  At least until Microsoft improves the author functions.